# GridView data getting cleared on PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am loading the user `control` in .aspx to display the `gridView` and dynamically creating the `CheckBox` template field in columns in code behind. Whenever i `check` or `uncheck`, `autopostback` is `triggered`.

Since i bind() the grid in `page_load`, it Skips the rebind the `gridView` after postback (if Not IsPostback() condition is added).

How to retain the data in the `GridView` with `Checkbox` changes after PostBack? User `control` is placed on  in aspx along with other labels and text box controls.

Please suggest how to regain the `GridView` data from this code after postback:

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim Values(5) As String
    Dim totalCount As Integer
    Dim dtcustAcctSignRelation = New DataTable()
    Dim lstCustInfo As ArrayList = TryCast(Session("CustInfo"), ArrayList)
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        For Each value As String In lstCustInfo
            Values(i) = value
            i = i + 1
        Next

        Calendar1.Visible = False

        lstRegInfo = CType(Session("secureURL"), Global.System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String))

        HideLeftPanelFromMasterPage()
        InitializeCustInfoPanel(Values)
        dtcustAcctSignRelation = RetrieveBSUCustomer(Values, 1, totalCount, dtcustAcctSignRelation) '*** Getting DataTable values
        LoadGridViewSignatoryGroup(Values(0).ToString(), dtcustAcctSignRelation) '*** Creating Template Fields and binding data to GridView
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please add your code so we can see where the problem is.

Comment: Added source code for your reference.